# Using pytest fixtures

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I want to handle dependencies and conditional test execution in my test suite which have over 100+ tests. For certain tests, it must pass so that it can move on to the next test in the suite. I am looking at a better way of checking the dependencies in each test and proceed only if the dependency is passed. Currently my tests are like this.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup(request):
  try:
    """
    Retrieve secrets from secrets manager
    """
    secret_name = "my-top-secret"
    secret_value = get_secret(secret_name)
    # secret_value = get_secret(secret_name)
    print(secret_value)
    secret_dict = json.loads(secret_value)
    UserName1 = secret_dict.get('UAT_USER_NAME_1')
    UserName7 = secret_dict.get('UAT_USER_NAME_7')
    UserName6 = secret_dict.get('UAT_USER_NAME_6')
    Password = secret_dict.get('UAT_PASSWORD')
    Client = secret_dict.get('UAT_CLIENT1')
    Uat_Url = secret_dict.get('BASE_URL_UAT')
    TestData_common.user_name1 = UserName1
    TestData_common.user_name6 = UserName6
    TestData_common.user_name7 = UserName7
    TestData_common.password = Password
    TestData_common.client = Client
    TestData_common.Url = Uat_Url
except WebDriverException as e:
    print('Collateral UAT seems to be down...> ', e)
    TestData_common.URL_FOUND = False

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
request.cls.driver = driver
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get(TestData_common.Url)
yield
driver.quit()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class Test_Counterparty:
    def test_001_login(self):
    """Login to UAT and click AGREE button in Site Minder"""
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    print('Successfully clicked AGREE button in SiteMinder')
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_click_agree_button()
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)

def test_002_enter_user_name(self):
    """Enter User name for Collateral"""
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    if not TestData_common.AGREE_BTN_FOUND:
        pytest.fail(reason="Site Minder AGREE button is not found...")
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_enter_user_name(TestData_common.user_name6, 'USER')
    if not TestData_common.USER1_ENABLED:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to enter User Name..')
    print('Entered User name as: ', TestData_common.user_name6)
    time.sleep(2)

def test_003_enter_password(self):
    """Enter Password for Collateral"""
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    if not TestData_common.AGREE_BTN_FOUND:
        pytest.fail(reason="Site Minder AGREE button is not found...")
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    if not TestData_common.USER1_ENABLED:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to enter User Name..')
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_enter_password(TestData_common.password, 'PASS')
    if not TestData_common.PASSWORD_ENABLED:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to enter Password..')
    print('Entered password:', TestData_common.password)
    time.sleep(2)

def test_004_click_login_button(self):
    """Click LOGIN button"""
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    if not TestData_common.AGREE_BTN_FOUND:
        pytest.fail(reason="Site Minder AGREE button is not found...")
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    if not TestData_common.USER1_ENABLED:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to enter User Name..')
    if not TestData_common.PASSWORD_ENABLED:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to enter Password..')
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    time.sleep(2)
    self.loginPage.do_click_login_button()
    if not TestData_common.LOGIN_BTN_FOUND:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to click LOGIN button..')
    print('Clicked LOGIN button')
    time.sleep(20)

def test_005_check_title(self):
    """Check Window Title"""
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    if not TestData_common.AGREE_BTN_FOUND:
        pytest.fail(reason="Site Minder AGREE button is not found...")
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    if not TestData_common.USER1_ENABLED:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to enter User Name..')
    if not TestData_common.PASSWORD_ENABLED:
        pytest.fail(reason='Unable to enter Password..')
     if not TestData_common.LOGIN_BTN_FOUND:
         pytest.fail(reason='Unable to click LOGIN button..')
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    time.sleep(2)
    title = self.driver.title
    if title == 'Citco Collateral':
        print('Successfully logged into Collateral')
        self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file('dashboard.png')
    else:
        TestData_common.SITE_MINDER_ERR = True
        self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file('test_cpty_SiteMinderError.png')
        pytest.fail(reason='Site Minder error:Not logged into Collateral UAT..')
    time.sleep(2)
```

There are many buttons and dropdowns and I don't want to check them in every test case, that would be too lengthy. Instead I am thinking of using fixtures to check for failure conditions like unable to click a button, unable to click a dropdown etc.
But not sure how should I implement it in the test suite.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't bother validating all buttons, etc. in every test case. That's why you have multiple test cases... if every test case contained every other test case they would all be too long. Each test should focus on testing one thing... get to that thing as quickly as possible, validate it, and exit the test. The other tests will take care of themselves.

Comment: You are also spending a lot of time in `setup()` setting up data for all tests... don't do that. Have each test set up it's own data. That keeps all your code simplified. If test 1 fails, you don't want to have to check a bunch of different variables in multiple methods across multiple files... that would be a nightmare.

Comment: Also, don't print success messages. They are a waste of time. If the script fails, you will get an error message with a full stack trace. You will instantly know how far the script got by what specific line it failed. Wading through hundreds of success messages to find the error message will only slow down your failure investigations.

Comment: I don't see any `driver.quit()` lines in any of your tests. Each test should create its own browser, execute the test steps, and close/quit the browser. That keeps separate tests from contaminating each other... each test run is as clean as possible. It also allows for parallel execution which makes your entire suite run much, much faster.

Comment: @JeffC, Thank you. I can't have driver.quit() for every test because its a complete UI application where I am testing every feature and each feature is dependent on the other. So it has to be run in a single driver instance, do all the validations and then quit. Regarding your 2nd point on failed tests, if test_010 fails because of certain condition(for eg button is not clickable or unable to enter data into a text field), there is no point in proceeding to test_011 because test_010 data is required...So is there a better method to handle such scenarios?

Comment: From reading your code and listening to your description, what you have done is turn each test *step* into a full blown "test". Tests should not be dependent on each other. As I've already stated, each test should be able to run in a single browser instance that is created and destroyed within the test. It sounds like you are doing an end-to-end test so best practice is to combine all of those steps (currently "tests") into a single test to accomplish that scenario.

Comment: What you need to do now is to identify your complete scenarios (not steps) and turn each of those into a single test. I would suggest you investigate the [page object model](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/encouraged/page_object_models) and start breaking down your scenario steps into methods in different page objects. It will take a small amount of extra time up front as you create each new page but the maintenance cost savings will be huge.